# Estimate Confidence Interval for ANCOVA difference of means similar to SAS

Tags: r

I need to present an ANCOVA model for some medical data. I'm used to work with SAS proc GLM and I wonder if it's possible to obtain confidence intervals for the difference of means as you get with SAS.
I'm using `LSmatrix` from `doBy` package to obtain the group means.

```
model <- aov(yield ~ block + N * P + K, npk)
library(doBy)
k1 <- LSmatrix(model, effect="block")
linest(model,K=k1)

  estimate       se df   t.stat      p.value block
1   54.025 1.977116 14 27.32515 1.510775e-13     1
2   57.450 1.977116 14 29.05747 6.479499e-14     2
3   60.775 1.977116 14 30.73922 2.981292e-14     3
4   50.125 1.977116 14 25.35258 4.229573e-13     4
5   50.525 1.977116 14 25.55490 3.792520e-13     5
6   56.350 1.977116 14 28.50111 8.457748e-14     6
```

I would like to get the difference of means block 1 - bloc 2 and a confidence interval (or a std. error), but I'm lost on how to proceed from here.

The result could be something like this:

```
    estimate     se upper.CI lower.CI
1-2   -3.425 ??????    ?????    ?????
1-3   -6.750 ??????    ?????    ?????
...
```

If anyone can tell me how to calculate the first, I can manange the rest :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify. My problem is where to find the data to compute a std. error for the difference of means.

Comment: If you're looking for data then please specify exactly what data you're looking for. I'm getting the feeling that what you may really want is statistical help from stats.stackexchange.com . All of the data is in the object `npk`. The linest() result is a list with essentially the exact data in your output. View the contents of `tmp` from my solution or `tmp <- linest(model,K=k1); str(tmp)`

Comment: Also, this may help https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I . Solution 1

```
> pacman::p_load(lsmeans, multcompView)
> 
> eindzl      <- lm(yield ~ block + N * P + K, npk)
> anova(eindzl)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: yield
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
block      5 343.29  68.659  4.3911 0.012954 * 
N          1 189.28 189.282 12.1055 0.003684 **
P          1   8.40   8.402  0.5373 0.475637   
K          1  95.20  95.202  6.0886 0.027114 * 
N:P        1  21.28  21.282  1.3611 0.262841   
Residuals 14 218.90  15.636                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> eindzl.rg   <- ref.grid(eindzl)
> eindzl.lsm  <- lsmeans(eindzl.rg, "block")
> cld(eindzl.lsm, alpha = .05)
 block lsmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 4     50.125 1.977116 14 45.88451 54.36549  1    
 5     50.525 1.977116 14 46.28451 54.76549  1    
 1     54.025 1.977116 14 49.78451 58.26549  12   
 6     56.350 1.977116 14 52.10951 60.59049  12   
 2     57.450 1.977116 14 53.20951 61.69049  12   
 3     60.775 1.977116 14 56.53451 65.01549   2   

Results are averaged over the levels of: N, P, K 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 6 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 

pairs(eindzl.lsm)
 contrast estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2      -3.425 2.796064 14  -1.225  0.8180
 1 - 3      -6.750 2.796064 14  -2.414  0.2160
 1 - 4       3.900 2.796064 14   1.395  0.7295
 1 - 5       3.500 2.796064 14   1.252  0.8049
 1 - 6      -2.325 2.796064 14  -0.832  0.9564
 2 - 3      -3.325 2.796064 14  -1.189  0.8348
 2 - 4       7.325 2.796064 14   2.620  0.1560
 2 - 5       6.925 2.796064 14   2.477  0.1960
 2 - 6       1.100 2.796064 14   0.393  0.9985
 3 - 4      10.650 2.796064 14   3.809  0.0190
 3 - 5      10.250 2.796064 14   3.666  0.0248
 3 - 6       4.425 2.796064 14   1.583  0.6217
 4 - 5      -0.400 2.796064 14  -0.143  1.0000
 4 - 6      -6.225 2.796064 14  -2.226  0.2856
 5 - 6      -5.825 2.796064 14  -2.083  0.3485

Results are averaged over the levels of: N, P, K 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 6 estimates 
>
```

II. Solution 2

Feel free to use your own equation for calculating the upper and lower bounds or visit [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) if you need help determining the formula. This example is based on the Standard Error and shows the code you need. CrossValidated is for statistics.

```
pacman::p_load(data.table,doBy)

model <- aov(yield ~ block + N * P + K, npk)
k1    <- LSmatrix(model, effect="block")
linest(model,K=k1)

tmp <- linest(model,K=k1)

tmp <- cbind(as.data.frame(tmp$coef), as.data.frame(tmp$grid))

tmp2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=4,nrow=9))
setnames(tmp2, c("group","estimate","lower bound of CI", "upper bound of CI"))

for(i in 1:5){
  n                  <- i + 1
  tmp2$estimate[i]   <- tmp$estimate[tmp$block == i] -  tmp$estimate[tmp$block == n]
  tmp2$group[i]      <- paste(i,n,sep="-")
  tmp2[i,3]          <- (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == i] - tmp$se[tmp$block == i]) - (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == n] + tmp$se[tmp$block == n])
  tmp2[i,4]          <- (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == i] + tmp$se[tmp$block == i]) - (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == n] - tmp$se[tmp$block == n])

}


for(i in 1:4){
  n                   <- i + 2
  nn                  <- 5+i    
  tmp2$estimate[nn]   <- tmp$estimate[tmp$block == i] -  tmp$estimate[tmp$block == n]
  tmp2$group[nn]      <- paste(i,n,sep="-")
  tmp2[nn,3]          <- (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == i] - tmp$se[tmp$block == i]) - (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == n] + tmp$se[tmp$block == n])
  tmp2[nn,4]          <- (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == i] + tmp$se[tmp$block == i]) - (tmp$estimate[tmp$block == n] - tmp$se[tmp$block == n])
}

tmp2

  group   estimate lower bound of CI upper bound of CI
1   1-2     -3.425         -7.379232         0.5292322
2   2-3     -3.325         -7.279232         0.6292322
3   3-4     10.650          6.695768        14.6042322
4   4-5     -0.400         -4.354232         3.5542322
5   5-6     -5.825         -9.779232        -1.8707678
6   1-3     -6.750        -10.704232        -2.7957678
7   2-4      7.325          3.370768        11.2792322
8   3-5     10.250          6.295768        14.2042322
9   4-6     -6.225        -10.179232        -2.2707678
```

Note that if you weren't choosing this particular package and function that you'd be able to get results like that without as much custom manipulation. Usually you type way less in R than in SAS.

Comment: As I understand, you are calculating the CI bounds for the difference of means as the difference of the bounds for the means (lower.mean.CI[block 1] - upper.mean.CI[block 2]) although you are not multiplying the std. error by 1.96 (`qnorm`). But even if you did. I don't think that's a licit way to compute a confidence interval for the difference.

Comment: @eindzl If you want a different formulation of the confidence interval, can't you modify it to your liking? Or provide an equation to do so. If you don't know what it should be then CrossValidated (stats.stackexchange.com) would be the place to go. The standard error is the sample estimate of standard deviation. My example was that the lower bound is the lowest difference where both estimates are within 1 standard deviation of the mean and vice versa for the upper bound. StackOverflow isn't for statistics though -- this is for programming -- CrossValidated is for statistics.

Comment: @eindzl I am adding another approach you may like better

Comment: Thank you @hack-r, the `pairs{lsmeans}` approach is what I was looking for. Probably I should have gone to crossvalidated, but I thougth it was more an issue of finding the right function and package.

Comment: @eindzl You're very welcome. There's a SE site for everything -- if you were looking for a tool (a package) then they actually want you to use the StackExchange called Software Recommendations.

Comment: Good a answer. Many other r packages now exist for this. One favorite here lately is emmeans.